# Does Multiplicative Version of Azuma's Inequality Hold?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

It is known that there are multiplicative version concentration inequalities for
sums of independent random variables. For example, the following
multiplicative version **Chernoff** bound.

---

**Chernoff bound:**

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables and $X_i \in$
$[0,1]$. Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\delta>0$,

$\Pr\left(Y \ge (1+\delta)EY \right) \le e^{-c\cdot(EY)\delta ^2},$

where $c$ is some absolute constant, e.g., c=1/3.

---

Now consider **dependent** random variables. A slight variant of **Azuma**'s inequality states the following.

---

**Azuma's Inequality:**

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be (dependent) random variables and $X_i \in
[0,1]$. Assume that there exists $\mu$, such that $ \Pr \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_{1},\ldots,X_{i-1}] \le \mu\right) = 1$. Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\lambda > 0$,

$\Pr\left(Y \ge n\mu+\lambda \right) \le e^{-2 \lambda^2/n}.$

---

Azuma's inequality is additive. My question is that does a
multiplicative version of Azuma's inequality such as the following
hold?

---

**My question:** does the following hold?

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be (dependent) random variables and $X_i \in
[0,1]$. Assume that there exists $\mu$, such that $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}] \le \mu\right) = 1.$ Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then for any $\delta>0$

$\Pr\left(Y \ge (1+\delta)n\mu \right) \le e^{-c\cdot n\mu \delta^2},$

where $c$ is some absolute constant.

---

**Note**: the standard Azuma's inequality does not imply the
multiplicative version when $n\mu \ll
\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Something is broken. Maybe you want $Y$ to be the mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ instead of the sum?

Comment: Are you only interested in the case of small $\delta$? You statement of Chernoff does not seem right to me for large $\delta$.

Comment: Also, take a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4056, section 2, particularly proposition 2.3, and see if that helps.

Comment: Ori, Thanks a lot! Your result is very relavant to my question. On the one hand, the proposition in your paper is stronger than my question; it's a uniform bound over n. But on the other hand, your result does not directly give an affirmative answer to my question. Using the notion in your paper, if m is an upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^t Y_i$, can I say $\sum_{i=1}^t X_i < 3m/2$ w.h.p.?

Comment: If by w.h.p. you mean a bound going to 0 with $m$, then I think the answer is yes. Just add more $X_i$ at the end that will make sure that $\sum Y_i$ is equal to $m$ and then apply proposition 2.3.


Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$
The "dependent" version of the multiplicative Chernoff bound can be proved quite similarly to the "independent" case. Indeed, let $E_{i-1}$ denote the conditional expectation given $X_1,\dots,X_{i-1}$, so that $E_{i-1}X_i\le\mu$ almost surely (a.s.) for $i=1,\dots,n$. Take any real $t\ge0$. By the convexity of $e^{tx}$ in $x$ and the conditions that $0\le X_i\le1$ and $E_{i-1}X_i\le\mu$, we have $e^{tX_i}\le1+(e^t-1)X_i$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
 E_{i-1}e^{tX_i}\le1+(e^t-1)E_{i-1}X_i\le1+(e^t-1)\mu\le\exp\{(e^t-1)\mu\} 
\end{equation*}
for $i=1,\dots,n$. So, by induction, for $j=1,\dots,n$ and $Y_j:=\sum_1^j X_i$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
 Ee^{tY_j}=EE_{j-1}e^{tY_j}=Ee^{tY_{j-1}}E_{j-1}e^{tX_j}\le Ee^{tY_{j-1}}\exp\{(e^t-1)\mu\},
\end{equation*}
whence, by induction, 
\begin{equation*}
 Ee^{tY}=Ee^{tY_n}\le\exp\{n(e^t-1)\mu\}. 
\end{equation*}
So, using Markov's inequality and then choosing $t=\ln(1+\de)$, we get 
\begin{align*}
 P(Y\ge(1+\de)n\mu)&\le e^{-(1+\de)n\mu t}Ee^{tY}
 \le\exp\{-(1+\de)n\mu t+n(e^t-1)\mu\} \\ 
 &=\exp\{-n\mu\psi(\de)\}, 
\end{align*}
where $\psi(u):=u-(1+u)\ln(1+u)$. 
Up to notation, this bound is the same as the known [multiplicative Chernoff bound in the "independent" case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)).

Since $\psi(u)\le-u^2/3$ for $u\in[0,3/2]$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 P(Y\ge(1+\de)n\mu)\le\exp\{-n\mu\de^2/3\} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
if $\de\in[0,3/2]$.

Note that (1) cannot hold for all $\de\ge0$, even in the "independent" case. Indeed, suppose that the $X_i$'s are iid with $P(X_1=1)=\mu=1-P(X_i=0)$, where $\mu:=1/n$ and $n\to\infty$. Then $Y$ will converge in distribution to  a random variable $\Pi$ with the Poisson distribution with parameter $1$, and (1) will yield 
\begin{equation*}
 P(\Pi\ge1+\de)\le\exp\{-\de^2/3\}.  
\end{equation*}
Since Poisson distributions are not subgaussian, the latter inequality cannot hold for all $\de\ge0$. So, (1) cannot hold for all $\de\ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such bounds are possible.  You can adapt the proof of Azuma's inequality to the multiplicative-error case, if you set it up correctly.
For example:

**Lemma 10 [[this paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~neal/Koufogiannakis13Nearly.pdf)]**.
*Let $Y=\sum_{t=1}^T x_t$ and $Z=\sum_{t=1}^T z_t$ 
be sums of non-negative random variables, 
where $T$ is a random stopping time with finite expectation,
and, for all $t$,
$|x_t-z_t|\le 1$ and
$$\textstyle
 E\big[\,x_{t} - z_{t} ~|\, \sum_{s< t} x_s, \sum_{s< t} z_s\,\big]
~\le~
 0.$$
Let $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then
$$\Pr\big[\,(1-\epsilon) Y \,\ge\, Z + A\, \big] ~\le~ \exp({-\epsilon}A).$$*

---

To apply this to your question, take $T=n$, $z_t=\mu$, and $A=\epsilon\, n\, \mu$.  Then you get
$$\Pr\big[\,Y \,\ge\, \frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}n\mu\, \big] ~\le~ \exp({-\epsilon^2}n\mu).$$

Comment: I should add that for your question you should be able to adapt the proof of Chernoff (with bound $\exp(-\epsilon^2 n \mu/3)$) directly to show that same bound.  For example, define $$\phi_t = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^t (1+\epsilon x_i) \times \exp(-\epsilon \mu (n-t))}{(1+\epsilon)^{(1+\epsilon)\mu n}}.$$  Then $\phi_0, \phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ is a super-martingale, so $E[\phi_n] \le \phi_0$.  From this inequality the desired bound follows as in the proof of standard Chernoff.